# Colors incorrect in Chromium

Tags: drivers, nvidia, google-chrome, chromium

In the attached screenshot, there is an image of the same webpage in Chromium 68.0.3440.75 and Firefox 61.0.1.  As you can see, the colors and fonts are unreadable in Chrome's rendering of the same webpage.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome a couple of times.

Chrome was working fine using a NVS 300 video card with the legacy 340 Nvidia driver, however the problem started when the box was upgraded to a GT1030 with Nvidia 390 driver.  It also occurs with a GT 710 Nvidia card.

There is a fix noted on several forums set chrome://flags/#force-color-profile to sRGB.  I've tried every way to set this flag, but it has no effect on the problem, so that isn't it.  Any clues as to what to try next?  [image: Bad chrome colors]

Answer (score 1):

I noticed on another forum that a user had issues with "GFX Hardware Acceleration" in chrome causing wierd colors.  In his case, turning it off fixed the issue, but in my case, turning settings => advanced => Use Hardware Acceleration when available to ON fixed the issue.